# How to force implementing a method of a class, without declaring the whole class abstract?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I often make a base class (most time base class for `Activity`) which is then extended by other classes in my project.

How can I force the clients to implement certain method?

I obviously cannot make just one method abstract without making the whole class abstract.

Comment: That's what abstract is for. Subclass `Activity` with an `abstract` class. And make your classes subclass that class.

Answer (score 2):

Make the class abstract. If you want to force an implementation, you're not going to want to instatiate the base class anyway. The other methods can still have concrete implementations, as follows;

```
public abstract class ServerListHtml extends HttpServlet {
    abstract public void foo();
    public int concrete() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

You can then define your own instantiable subclass if you need a basic "default" set of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Interface`. Then if some one want to use this he has to implement all those methods. In other ways can't force to implement all methods.

Comment: OP wants to have some concrete methods.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use an `Interface` for some subclasses or you may really make the `Superclass` abstract to force every child to instantiate it, making the superclass not really instantiatable.

Maybe you should look for a good inheritance from an `abstract class` or really thinking about using an `Interface`.